# Python: correct Exception to raise

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python, if a set of `if` and `elif` conditions are not satisfied, the `else` statement is reached and executed.

How, and raise which exception type, should a developer notify that such point in the code should not be reached?

Example:

```
if condition1:
    # do something
elif condition2:
    # do something
else:
    raise ShouldVeNeverGotHereException
```

This is to ensure that at least one of the above `if` conditions actually evaluates to `True`. If there is a pattern more elegant to achieve what I describe, please suggest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should never write code that can result in loose ends. But assuming you must, probably the best type of Exception to raise is a `ValueError`.

```
>>> foo = 3
>>> if foo == 1:
    pass
elif foo == 2:
    pass
else:
    raise ValueError('foo is unexpected value: %s' % foo)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#41>", line 6, in <module>
    raise ValueError('foo is unexpected value: %s' % foo)
ValueError: foo is unexpected value: 3
```

Comment: I'd love to hear what is not helpful or wrong about my answer, to deserve a downvote. That way I can improve my answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`assert`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement):

```
if condition1:
    do_stuff()
elif condition2:
    do_stuff()
else:
    assert condition1 and condition2, "condition1 and condition2 is False. Do not continue" # Or something similar
```

Comment: Assert is traditionally something you want to do at the *start* of your code, and usually it is not something you use to check specific values, but rather to make sure objects can be interacted with in the way you expect. For instance, using assert to check if a designated file output path exists before starting the logic of creating the content. In the docs: "Assert statements are a convenient way to insert debugging assertions into a program". A variable with a wrong value during runtime is not a debugging problem.

Comment: I agree with @InbarRose 's comment about the use of `assert`. Your answer does cater for what I ask about "ensure that at least one of the above if conditions actually evaluates to True", but @InbarRose 's answer hits the nail on its head with regards to the entire question.